# Reducing git pack size with removing binary files

Tags: git, git-gc

The repo is containing folder with binary files and that causes increasing the pack size in .git folder, now .git is ~800MB (80% of total size) and repo size is 1GB.

I've tried to delete the folder and commit it and do all these `git gc, git fsck, git prune,...` but no change in size of the pack.

there are a lot of suggestion with a simple search on google but none of them working for me!

so how can I reduce my repo size, should I delete files from history **one by one** which is definitely not a solution for me as there are lots of them!!

Comment: As long as there are commits containing the big files, you cannot reduce your repo size. Look at git filter-repo (https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/) for automatic cleaning of history. Be careful, it means rewriting history, so not advised for already published and shared repository.

Comment: Thank you, actually this is was the key that I missed! "_commits containing the big files_", so I like this library more as I think it is more safer than the proposed answer because I can specify the folder and not just base on blob size.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history

Answer (score 1):

The solutions is to remove large binary files, but not one at time by hand.

Instead you should use the [BFG tool](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) powerful tool.

Here is an example (as described by the above link):

```sh
git clone --mirror git://example.com/some-big-repo.git

java -jar bfg.jar --strip-blobs-bigger-than 100M some-big-repo.git

cd some-big-repo.git

git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive

git push
```

Comment: Thanks! This one is also working, but just relay on blob size is kind of the restriction! I've tried it and I can save more than the command `git-filter-repo` but not possible to use it on folder just the file extensions.

Comment: Please, accept the solution it solved your problem. ;)